# How to use CSS in order to change <div> so it would look and behave as <p>?

Tags: html, css

The title explains itself I belive. My CSS skill is not good enough to make it work, or predict everything.

I made an simple fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f6oe9umb/3/

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
<div class="fakeparagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
<div class="fakeparagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</div>
<div class="fakeparagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
<div class="fakeparagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</div>
<div class="fakeparagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</div>
```

In this case simple margin-bottom should be good enough. But is it? And even if - how to find the correct value?

Comment: If you select the element in the dev tools in Chrome for example you can see how Chrome natively styles a `p`, you can copy this for the `div`.

Comment: This looks like great answer, yet I'm not experienced enough - where exactly can I find those native styles? And are they the same for Firefox and other browsers?

Comment: ...why not just use a `p`?

Comment: Because You can not nest them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the default css for browsers [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp), and there it is:

```
p {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

so say you got a `<div class="fake-p"/>`, and the styling:

```
.fake-p {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

But to be honest each browser has their default setting to html tags (different browser might have different styling but some are the same) and they can change it any time, so I suggest you to directly use a `p` tag if you want its behaviour.

Comment: The reason is, that I can nest divs, while i can not do the same with paragraphs. This is why it's handy for me to fake some paragraphs in some situations. Thanks for correct answer!

Answer (score -1):

I think that should make it look like a normal p:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .fakeparagraph {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately - it does not :(